# How to determine which implementation of an abstract class to use?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

What would be the best way to determine which implementation of an abstract class to call based on a certain variable or defining feature?

**Code Example:**

```
public abstract class FileProcesser
{
    private string _filePath;

    protected FileProcessor(string filePath)
    {
        if (filePath == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath");
        }

        // etc etc

        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    // some example methods for this file
    public abstract int GetFileDataCount();
    public abstract IEnumerable<FileItem> GetFileDataItems();
}

// specific implementation for say, a PDF type of file
public class PdfFileProcesser : FileProcessor
{
    public PdfFileProcessor(string filePath) : base(filePath) {}

    // implemented methods
}

// specific implementation for a type HTML file
public class HtmlFileProcessor : FileProcessor
{
    public HtmlFileProcessor(string filePath) : base(filePath) {}

    // implemented methods 
}

public class ProcessMyStuff()
{
    public void RunMe()
    {
        // the code retrieves the file (example dummy code for concept)
        List<string> myFiles = GetFilePaths();

        foreach (var file in myFiles)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".pdf")
            {
                FileProcessor proc = new PdfFileProcessor(file);
                // do stuff
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".html")
            {
                FileProcessor proc = new HtmlFileProcessor(file);
                // do stuff
            }
            // and so on for any types of files I may have
            else 
            { 
                // error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel as though there is a "smarter" way to do this with the use of better OO concepts. The code I wrote up is an example to demonstrate what I am trying to understand, sorry if there are simple errors but the basic idea is there. I know this is a specific example, but I think this applies to many other types of problems too.

Comment: Look into "abstract factory pattern".

Comment: This is pretty much the base case for a factory. http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory

Comment: You seem to be on the way to implementing the Strategy pattern. I'd be more inclined to make a Processor class that contains an IProcessFiles interface, which defines the basic methods involved, and run processors for each type individually, each only looking for the type of file they can deal with. It may be less efficient, but it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a factory to retrieve your processor:

```
    foreach (var file in myFiles)
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
        IFileProcessor proc = FileProcessorFactory.Create(extension);
        // do stuff
    }
```

Then your factory is something like:

```
public static class FileProcessorFactory 
{
    public static IFileProcessor Create(string extension) {
        switch (extension) {
            case "pdf":
                return new PdfFileProcessor();
            case "html":
                return new HtmlFileProcessor();
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we are using an interface, which your abstract class would inherit from. This allows any of your inheriting types to be returned.

Comment: To be fair, this just moves the if chain, and won't adapt well to additional strategies. Any new FileProcessor will require a recompile of the assembly with the factory, after a new `case` is added.

Comment: I agree with mayabelle. If you have your processors and factory method in lib A and lib B add new processor, then just let B have its own factory method that call's A and fallback on its own processor if nothing is found in A.
Alternatively you can put attributes on processor classes with their extension, and use reflections to choose the right one... but frankly, I doubt it is worth it. Or you can convert the previous if into a global dictionary... But sometimes a good old if is not that bad.